# UITextView size not changing size after text has wrapped until second character is typed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have spent at least 10 hours trying to figure this out and I am stuck. I am trying to have `UITextView` within a `UITableViewCell` that automatically expands to the size of the textview when the number of lines in the text view has changed. The table cell is inside a static table view. I have looked at almost every question about this on stackoverflow and nothing seems to be working.

My test project is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5301042/AutomaticResizingTextView.zip).

I have created a custom class that automatically resizes the textview. It works perfectly when not in a table cell. You can see this in the example project. There are two instances of the textview; one in a regular view where the textview resizes correctly, and another in a tableview. In the table cell, it doesn't resize until the second character on the next line has been typed. It is odd, because when I log the height of the textview it says that the value of frame.size.height has changed but the text view does not change size.

One thing that worked was creating a custom table cell and then overriding the `layoutSubviews` method but the problem with that was the bottom border line on the table cell lagged and created an ugly line across the screen. I looked for a solution but could not figure out how to prevent this.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your project and make it work by :

- In Tbl View Controller in storyboard, remove AutoLayout. Although you don't set any constraint for the text view, at run time some constraints will be set automatically, and that will clash when the text view tries to change its frame.
- In storyboard, set the autoresizing mask of the text view to default (Fix top, Fix Left, flexible right margin, flexible bottom margin).

It will work correctly now.

Comment: Thank you so much! This *almost* works perfectly. The only thing now is that when you go back to there being only one line it cuts off the bottom of the line.

Comment: @SamB : Can you elaborate it more ?

Comment: Type a character which goes below the baseline (like a g or j) and then have the textview expand to a new line. Then if you delete until you have one line again, the textview shrinks and cuts of the bottom of the character the first time it changes lines.

Comment: @SamB : i can't simulate the issue.

Comment: This what it looks like for me when I type something that goes to the next line, then delete until it goes back to only one line. http://i.imgur.com/mPCtAnM.png 
Do you have the middle resizing masks enabled?

Comment: No, don't enable autoresizing mask here since you change the text view frame manually

Comment: When I don't set the middle resize masks for the textview the textview resizes but the text doesn't show up in the second line initially. Sorry this is so much trouble. I appreciate your help.

Comment: May be you can upload your latest code somewhere and let me try to download it again. I'll see what's happening.

Comment: I have been messing with it and I am not exactly sure what I did to fix it but it works now! At first setting autoResizing mask to nil in viewdidload worked but now when I took it away it still works. Thank you!